# Perl- insert data into SQL while reading the columns from an array?

Tags: sql, perl, dbi, dbd

The question is simpler than it sounds(i think).
I have a database table called `table` and I'm trying to insert data in the column called `first`.
Here is a part of the code:

```
 my $stmt = $dbh->prepare($sql);
@array=("first","second","third");    
$sql = "INSERT INTO table($array[0]) VALUES(?)";
$stmt->execute($some_value);
```

The program runs without warnings, but it simply fills the table with 0, which is different from `$some_value`.

Comment: You use `$sql` in the `prepare` statement before you assign a value to it? Is that right?

Comment: @mob I don't think it's right, but it's true ;-)

Comment: You can't change the SQL after you've prepared the statement and expect it to work!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all, naming a table `table` is a bad idea because it is likely that you have to escape its name every now and then.

Secondly, your statements are in the wrong order. You firstly prepare some statement (with unknown content) and only then assign an SQL statement to that variable.

Try this:

```
my @columns = ("first","second","third");    
my $sql = "INSERT INTO table(" . $dbh->quote_identifier($columns[0]) . ") VALUES(?)";
my $stmt = $dbh->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute($some_value);
```

I didn't test this, but it *may* be necessary to write

```
my $sql = "INSERT INTO `table` (" . $dbh->quote_identifier($columns[0]) . ") VALUES(?)";
```

because `table` is a keyword in SQL. Better name it according to the things it contains, not to its shape.

As @ikegami pointed out in a comment, it's also better to let the DBI driver quote the column names (with `quote_identifier()` instead of using them directly), because it's always dangerous to build SQL statements from (untrusted) variables.

---

Perhaps you are confused how statement preparation works. The basic statement cannot be varied after a call to `prepare`, which means in

```
INSERT INTO mytable (col1, col2) VALUES (?,?)
```

you can only supply different values for the two `?` placeholders and then re-execute the very same statement with different values for these `?`s.
For example, it's **not possible to write**

```
INSERT INTO ? (?, ?) VALUES (?,?)
```

and then `prepare` that statement and then run

```
$sth->execute('my_table', 'col1', 'col2', 'val1', 'val2');
```

This won't work.

---

If you want to run two different INSERT statements (for two different columns), then you need to prepare twice. Depending on your actual case you can **either**

```
my $stmt_for_col1 = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO my_table (col1) VALUES (?)");
my $stmt_for_col2 = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO my_table (col2) VALUES (?)");
```

and then execute the two statements as often as you like and in arbitrary order:

```
$stmt_for_col1->execute('value_for_col1');
$stmt_for_col2->execute('value_for_col2');
$stmt_for_col1->execute('value_for_col1');
```

**or** use only one statement at a time:

```
my $stmt = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO my_table (col1) VALUES (?)");
$stmt->execute('value_for_col1');
$stmt->execute('value_for_col1');

$stmt = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO my_table (col2) VALUES (?)");
$stmt->execute('value_for_col2');
$stmt->execute('value_for_col2');
```

The `prepare` step is done once per statement, the `execute` step can (and often is) run in a loop to make the statement execute with different values.

Comment: you are right, my confusion was due to the fact that i didn't know how to avoid a prepare-execute sequence in a loop.